# Can regexp return key/value pairs in a structure?

Tags: regex, matlab, token, key-value, matlab-struct

Let's say I have a character array with key/value pairs:

```
ch = sprintf('name: John\nsex: M\n')
ch =
    'name: John
     sex: M
     '
```

This is just a sample. The actual data is in a file and has many pairs. I can use `regexp` to get tokens, then use a for loop to assign them to a structure:

```
lns = regexp(ch, '(\w*):\s(.*?)\n', 'tokens');
for i = 1:numel(lns)
    myStruct.(lns{i}{1}) = lns{i}{2};
end

myStruct = 

  struct with fields:

    name: 'John'
     sex: 'M'
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this, like using `regexp(ch, expr, 'names')`?

Comment: Do you know the keys in advance?  That is, will they always be 'name' and 'sex'?

Comment: If we avoid _for_ loop, it may potentially improve performance at least.

Comment: @informaton I don't know keys in advance. From regexp documentation, it seems that known keys are needed.

Comment: You are right.  Sorry, I was about to give example using known keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the for loop by collecting your key/value pairs into a single cell array and then passing the contents of that as a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to [`struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html):

```
args = [lns{:}];
myStruct = struct(args{:});
```

And the output:

```
myStruct = 

  struct with fields:

    name: 'John'
     sex: 'M'
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the use of [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) and use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read from the file, which may improve performance:

```
strs = textscan(fileID, '%s', 'Delimiter', ':');
myStruct = struct(strs{1}{:});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested the performance, with 75 pairs, this seems a little faster than `for` loop, although the difference is very minor.

Comment: @XiangruiLi: I added an option using `textscan` instead of `regexp`. Hopefully that might boost performance.

Comment: That might be faster. But for my case, I can't use '%s', since the `value` can have space inside

Comment: @XiangruiLi: I updated with a fix that allows spaces. :)